# How to create a column in a data frame based on the values of another two columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I am pre-formatting some data for a tax filing and I am using python to automate some of the excel work. I have a data frame with three columns: Account; Opposite Account; Amount. I only have the names of the opposite account and the values, but the values for the same pair of account - opposite account should be exactly the same. For example:

```
Account       Opposite Acc.      Amount

              Cash               -240.56
              Supplies            240.56
              Dentist            -10.45
              Gum                 10.45
```

From that, I can deduce that Cash is the opposite of Supplies and Dentist is the opposite to Gum, so I would like my output to be:

```
Account      Opposite Acc.      Amount

Supplies      Cash               -240.56
Cash          Supplies            240.56
Gum           Dentist            -10.45
Dentist       Gum                 10.45
```

Right now I doing this manually by using str.contains

```
df = df.assign(en_accounts = df['Opposite Acc.'])
df['Account'] = df['Account'].fillna("0")
df.loc[df['Account'].str.contains('Cash'), 'Account'] = 'Supplies'
```

But there are many variables and I wonder if there is a way to automate this process in python. One strategy could be: if two rows add up to 0, the accounts are a match --> therefore when item A (such as supplies) happens in "Opposite Acc.", item B (such as Cash) is put in the same row but in "Account".

This is what I have so far:

```
df['Amount'] = np.abs(df["Amount"])
c1 = df['Amount']
c2 = df['Opposing Acc.']

for i in range(1,len(c1)-1):
    p = c1[i-1]
    x = c1[i]
    n = c1[i+1]

    if p == x:
         for i in range(1,len(c2)-1):
                a = c2[i-1]
                df.loc[df['en_account']] = a
```

But I get the following error: "None of [Index[....]\n dtype='object', length=28554)] are in the [index]"

Comment: I know thats’ unlikely to happen, but keep it mind that there might be 2 (or more) pairs that add up to zero simultaneously (in the case their amount spent is the same). I’d make a quick verification beforehand just to be sure there are no cases like that.

Comment: @L.B.  the code I have so far just checks if the amounts are the same, but I can't get python to replace the value in the "Account" column when the if statement is satisfied. Do you think that would cause an error in this case?

Comment: I think there is a quite simple solution for your problem, but that would require that your original *df* have the pairs (Acc. & Op.Acc) followed by one another (just like in the example you gave). Is the dataframe ordered this way?

Comment: @L.B. most of them are ordered this way, but some are not . And even then, my solution produces and error